# Server parameters for Differential Zero Knowledge?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation, differential-privacy

I'm working to use Differential Zero Knowledge proof on client local data before sharing with server. May I know which parameters need to be established at server side as to verify that the client is not cheating?

I've looked at ["Differential Secrecy for Distributed Data and Applications to Robust Differentially Secure Vector Summation"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.10618.pdf) and
["The Bounded Gaussian Mechanism for Differential Privacy"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.17230.pdf) but I'm still stuck defining the setup of the server.

Comment: I've made some extensive edits, please check for correctness. Note that I think the term should be "Differential ZK" not "Differentially ZK"; the paper uses that only in the combination "(ε, δ)-Differentially ZK".

Comment: Sure ! Your edits are much clear.